# Почему картины пишут?

Tags: употребление-слов

Интересно, вот графические рисунки рисуют, а картины почему-то пишут. Хотя процесс рисования происходит и там, и там.

Comment: Обратитесь к художникам.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В русском языке изначально было только *писать*. По происхождению близко к *пёстрый*. Сначала значило: покрывать узором, "пестрить красками", а на Украине еще недавно "писанками" назывались пестро раскрашенные пасхальные яйца. Ср. слова "расписной" — "пестрый".
Сюда же живопись, живописать, живописный — живо писанный (писать с живой натуры).
[Пиджак, пилот, пионер, писать | pochemyneinache.com](http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/15/str242.html)

РИСОВАТЬ пришло потом, заимствовано из польского, где *rysowac* – "рисовать" восходит к немецкому *reissen* – "чертить".
[РИСОВАТЬ | slovopedia.com](http://www.slovopedia.com/25/208/1651749.html)

Поэтому картины и рисуют, и пишут, но на правильном русском языке предков всё же пишут.

Comment: Почему - еще недавно? И сейчас называются.))))

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, кистью - пишут, а карандашом - рисуют. Т.е. живопись - только "пишут". Хотя, говорят же "рисовать картину". Не знаю, если это грубая ошибка. Зависит от контекста? Инстинкт настойчиво предлагает говорить "писать" (кистью, красками, маслом, акварелью и т.п.)

[РИСОВАТЬ](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC/)

Answer (score 1):

Я присоединяюсь к natasha.
Этимология - хорошо, но тут вопрос явно не о том, что поведала Людмила (изложенное само по себе не оспариваю).

Красками пишут. Как чернилами и вообще всем, что зачерпывают, набирают и т.п. Сам инструмент (кисти, перья, пальцы) при этом не расходуется.

Карандашом, мелками, углем - рисуют.

Впрочем, тут тоже не все ясно.
Всегда интересно, как называют профи процесс "сухого письма/рисунка". И к какой категории относится, например, процесс набивки на ткани. Почему, наконец, светопись - именно "пись"?

> Хотя, говорят же "рисовать картину".

Это грубое отступление от профессиональных норм, но никак не ощибка с точки зрения языка. Имхо.