# "И там, и там". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в конструкции "и там, и там", и почему? (нужна ли запятая перед "и почему"? Я совершенно «не умею пунктуацию», хелп плиз!

Comment: Дубликат вроде... https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/24078/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82 Пользуйтесь окном Искать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, постановка запятой будет зависеть от контекста и от воли автора.

С одной стороны, "запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством повторяющихся союзов *и*... *и*", с другой стороны, "при двух однородных членах с повторяющимся союзом *и* запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство" ([§86. Однородные члены, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm)).

Именно для того, чтобы понять, есть ли тесное смысловое единство, нужно видеть контекст, а поскольку понятие "тесное смысловое единство" четко не определено, то в конечном итоге решает автор.

Примеры:

> Вопрос № 292170
>   Добрый день! Интересует обособление фигуры " и там (?) и там (?)". Фрагмент текста такой: "Я успел поучиться в двух университетах. И там(?) и там (?) лекторы только упивались собой, а студенты прогуливали их лекции." Заранее спасибо за ответ!
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Запятые не нужны:  И там и там лекторы только упивались собой...

(http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=292170++++)

> И там, и там дети зачастую переживали и осмысляли боль предыдущих поколений. [Борис Рогинский. Голубой вагон // «Знание - сила», 2005]